# Pagenumbers disappear when using a scrlayer-ed approach

Tags: page-numbering

I'm using the below code which was supplied as an answer to another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551384/how-to-create-a-multicol-within-a-page-frame-spanning-multiple-pages).

Problem is: In the very moment the pagestyles are declared with `\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{topbox}`, the pagenumber disappears. If the lines of `\DeclarePageStyleByLayers...` are marked (=taken out=without frame) then the pagenumber appears.

I'm actually *olny* using this code which was given to me, and I'm only understanding this on the surface. I would have expected that Tex puts the pagenumber and then would overlay the frame, but obviously that's not what happenes.

I would like to have the pagenumber within the frame.
How to achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\marginpadding}
\setlength{\marginpadding}{4pt}

\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
  addheight=2\marginpadding,
  addwidth=2\marginpadding,
  addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
  addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{topbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{midbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  height={\pdfpageheight-\zposy{textbottom}sp-\layeryoffset-\baselineskip+\marginpadding},
  contents={%
  \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{bottombox}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{topbox}   % delete the whole line to see the pagenumber to appear
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{midpage}{midbox}     % delete the whole line to see the pagenumber to appear
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{lastpage}{bottombox} % delete the whole line to see the pagenumber to appear
\pagestyle{midpage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]       
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\zsaveposy{textbottom}
\thispagestyle{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The page number disappears because that's part of the pagestyle that has been replaced. To get it back, you just need to add another layer that contains the page number, along with anything else you want in the footer, and add the appropriate extra distance to extend the frame.

This version puts the page number centered and doesn't do any formatting with it. It will require modification if you want anything fancier, such as odd-even page changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\marginpadding}
\setlength{\marginpadding}{4pt}

\DeclareNewLayer[foot,contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\centering\thepage}}]{pagenum}
\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
  addheight=2\marginpadding+\footskip,
  addwidth=2\marginpadding,
  addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
  addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{topbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{midbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  height={\pdfpageheight-\zposy{textbottom}sp-\layeryoffset-\baselineskip+ \marginpadding},
  contents={%
  \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{bottombox}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{topbox,pagenum}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{midpage}{midbox,pagenum}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{lastpage}{bottombox,pagenum}
\pagestyle{midpage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]       
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\zsaveposy{textbottom}
\thispagestyle{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Based on this code I produced what you will find in 'my anwer'. It includes the pagenum into the frame on the last page.

Answer (score 3):

You could load package `scrlayer-scrpage` and add all layers of page style `scrheadings` to  the new pagestyles. Then you can use `\cfoot` or `\ofoot` etc. for the page number.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\marginpadding}
\setlength{\marginpadding}{4pt}

\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
  addheight=2\marginpadding,
  addwidth=2\marginpadding,
  addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
  addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{topbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{midbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  height={\pdfpageheight-\zposy{textbottom}sp-\layeryoffset-\baselineskip+\marginpadding},
  contents={%
  \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{bottombox}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{topbox}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{midpage}{midbox}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{lastpage}{bottombox}

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{firstpage}{#1}%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{midpage}{#1}%
    \AddLayersToPageStyle{lastpage}{#1}%
}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}


\pagestyle{midpage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]       
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\zsaveposy{textbottom}
\thispagestyle{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

or you could use

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\marginpadding}
\setlength{\marginpadding}{4pt}

\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
  addheight=2\marginpadding,
  addwidth=2\marginpadding,
  addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
  addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{topbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{midbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  height={\pdfpageheight-\zposy{textbottom}sp-\layeryoffset-\baselineskip+\marginpadding},
  contents={%
  \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{bottombox}

\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{\cfoot{\pagemark}}
\newpairofpagestyles{midpage}{\cfoot{\pagemark}}
\newpairofpagestyles{lastpage}{\cfoot{\pagemark}}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{firstpage}{topbox}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{midpage}{midbox}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{lastpage}{bottombox}


\pagestyle{midpage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]       
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\zsaveposy{textbottom}
\thispagestyle{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

If the page number should be in the boxes then add `\footskip` and maybe `\dp\strutbox` to the height of all boxes and remove the changed height for the layer `bottombox`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\marginpadding}
\setlength{\marginpadding}{4pt}

\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
  addheight=2\marginpadding+\footskip+\dp\strutbox,% changed
  addwidth=2\marginpadding,
  addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
  addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{topbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  contents={%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{midbox}
\DeclareNewLayer[clone=topbox,
  %height={\pdfpageheight-\zposy{textbottom}sp-\layeryoffset-\baselineskip+\marginpadding},% removed
  contents={%
  \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
  \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
  \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{bottombox}

\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{\cfoot{\pagemark}}
\newpairofpagestyles{midpage}{\cfoot{\pagemark}}
\newpairofpagestyles{lastpage}{\cfoot{\pagemark}}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{firstpage}{topbox}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{midpage}{midbox}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{lastpage}{bottombox}


\pagestyle{midpage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]       
\end{multicols}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\zsaveposy{textbottom}
\thispagestyle{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now used the version of Karl and added a layer *pagenum lastpage* that enables the inclusion of the last pagenumber *into* the frame. Additionaly I fiddled the frame of *lastpage* a bit longer to provide the space for the pagenumber. Here's what it looks like for me now:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%   PAGESPACES
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=0.7cm, top=0.7cm, bottom=0.2cm, includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
% PAGE BODY
\setlength{\textheight}{780pt}  
% TOP SPACES
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}                          
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.7cm}           
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}            
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}               
% RIGHT SPACES
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0cm}
% BOTTOM SPACES
\setlength{\footskip}{4ex}      
\setlength{\footheight}{0ex}        

% MARGIN
\newlength{\marginpadding}
\setlength{\marginpadding}{8pt}

% PAGENUM 
\DeclareNewLayer[foot, contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\centering  \textsl{Seite \thepage \hspace{0.5pt} von \pageref{LastPage}}}}]{pagenum}
% PAGENUM LASTPAGE
\DeclareNewLayer[foot,%
    addvoffset=-\zposy{textbottom}sp+\topmargin+\footskip+\marginpadding,
    contents={\parbox{\layerwidth}{\centering  \textsl{Seite \thepage \hspace{0.5pt} von \pageref{LastPage}}}}]{pagenumLastPage}

% TOPOBOX
\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
height={ \textheight+0.5\footskip},
addheight=2\marginpadding+\footskip,
addwidth=2\marginpadding,
addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
contents={%
    \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
    \putUR{\line(-1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
    \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{topbox}

% MIDBOX
\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
height={ \textheight+0.5\footskip},
addheight=2\marginpadding+\footskip,
addwidth=2\marginpadding,
addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
contents={%
    \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
    \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{midbox}

% BOTTOMBOX
\DeclareNewLayer[textarea,background,mode=picture,
height={\textheight-\zposy{textbottom}sp+\topmargin+\footskip+2\marginpadding},
addheight=2\marginpadding+\footskip,
addwidth=2\marginpadding,
addhoffset=-\marginpadding,
addvoffset=-\marginpadding,
contents={%
    \putLL{\line(1,0){\LenToUnit{\layerwidth}}}%
    \putLR{\line(0,1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
    \putUL{\line(0,-1){\LenToUnit{\layerheight}}}%
}]{bottombox}

\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{topbox, pagenum}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{midpage}{midbox, pagenum}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{lastpage}{bottombox, pagenumLastPage}
\pagestyle{midpage}

\begin{document}
    
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1-10]       
    \end{multicols}
    
    \lipsum[1-2]
    
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{multicols}
    \zsaveposy{textbottom}
    \thispagestyle{lastpage}
    
\end{document}
```